# Silverstripe 3.1; multiple validations using getCMSValidator in dataobject

Tags: validation, content-management-system, backend, silverstripe

I am trying to validate a dataobject prior to database insertion. I am using the function getCMSValidator() for that. As only one validator is available (RequiredValidator), I made one myself, extending Validator, that checks if field value(s) are unique in the database.

```
function getCMSValidator() {
    return new UniqueValidator("DBTable",array('Field1','Field2'));
}
```

This is working. But now I find myself in the position that I have to do multiple validations, e.g. both UniqueValidator AND RequiredValidator.

How should I approach this? Preferably without creating a new validator?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar before by extending RequiredFields rather than Validator. Anything that extends Validator has a 'php' function that returns a boolean. Inside this you can check for required fields as well as any further validation of your own.

```
class ExampleValidator extends RequiredFields {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(array('Field1','Field2'));
    }

    public function php($data) {
        $valid = parent::php($data);
        // If $valid is false here you could return immediately 
        // or continue with further validation of your own
        // ...   
        return $valid;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But I do not want to create a new Validator every time I need an object validated. I'd like to program a RequiredFields class, and a UniqueFields class, that I can use side by side.

Comment: So you want to carry out both types of validation? The above approach would do that, with the required fields validation being done first, then proceed to do the unique field validation. You can still create your UniqueFields validator to accept a list of fields that should be unique and a list of fields that are required, so you only need the one validator.